# how to copy one folder to server using ftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, terminal-server

i need your help i'm new for using linux...
i want to copy one folder to server..
i'm still confuse to use ftp mput...
will you tell me step by step??

i want to copy foldet "dataTable-1.6" at /home/qa/html/dataTable-1.6
into html folder at server../www/html..
how to do that?

```
1> qa@qadesktop2:~$ ftp 10230.35.211
2> fill password
3> ftp>cd www/html
4> ftp>mput
   (local-files)/home/qa/html/dataTable-1.6/*
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How you would normally copy all of the files in a folder to a remote location via FTP :

** First move to the local directory before starting the ftp client **

```
$ cd /home/qa/html/dataTable-1.6
$ ftp ftp.servername.com
```

** Login using loginname and password **

```
ftp> cd www/html
ftp> mput *
```

** mput will copy all files found at the current local directory 
    matching the attributes (* will match all filenames, *.zip will 
    only upload files ending with .zip) **

The standard FTP client does not support recursive copying (i.e. Folders within folders).

Check out lftp or ncfp. These are more featureful ftp clients, which support recursive transfers, syncing and a lot more.

Comment: mput ask me confirmation for each file. I had to execute ftp command "prompt". But then it transfered not recursively. "mput -r *" also does not seem recursive :-(